# Hidden alarm at everyday 12AM

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, alarm

I have the Lenovo Moto Z Unlocked with sadly still Android M.

There's a hidden alarm everyday at 12 midnight, and it doesn't show it in the original clock app, which I haven't used an app other than that for alarms.

How can I diagnose this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. It turns out TimeTune was doing this (even though it is only a reminder app). I uninstalled and it disappeared.

Comment: It turned out to be TimeTune for me too. The 12am alarm was showing on my lock screen. Uninstalling the app removed the hidden alarm from bring displayed on my lock screen.

Comment: What was your way of discovering it?

Answer (score 0):

Check for **Google Calendar** or any other task app that you have installed. Possibly you might have setup notification as daily and time might have be automatically selected as 12 PM.

Do remember that **Factory Reset** is the final resort to solve your issues, including this one as well.

Comment: I haven't used another app for alarms.

Answer (score 0):

I did everything that anyone in any sites suggested but it didn't solve, then I uninstalled clock app updates,restart the phone,and the hidden alarm disappeared!